# what is the effect of using 'ping -m' (tagging the packets)

Tags: linux, ping, packet

i was going through the man pages of ping and i found a -m option there..
so how does this effect my packets?

its something like tagging the packets.

```
ping 8.8.8.8 -m 2
```

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man8/ping.8.html

I tried googling it but , i could find none..
can someone please help me out?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty nice explanation of the MARK feature:
http://andys.org.uk/bits/2010/01/27/iptables-fun-with-mark/

Comment: is the IPTables mark same as 'ping -m' mark option?

because as far as i could find data about it on the internet, i could learn that the ping -m option uses some 'SO_MARK' option of the socket interface to tag the packet...

is that right?

Comment: Yes, they both use the SO_MARK. This isn't limited to either applications though, I simply choose the article because it explained in a neat fashion how it can be used, not just what it is.